# Unable to get request data in asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

in asp.net pageload method I am trying to get request data using

```
Request.Form["keyname"]
Request.Query
```

but all are empty but when I run fiddler in inspector>>raw I am getting this

```
POST http://localhost:50844/Success.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:50844
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 15583
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Origin: null
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=ax0e4j1ucaghsarowzmvgoep

valuestr=abc&randomnum=99389
```

I need to get values of valuestr and randomnum,how can I do this

Comment: asp.net is built to make it very easy to manage `post` data. If you have `<asp:textbox ID="txt" runat="server" />` then you can access its value using its ID. for example `this.txt.Text = "something";`. Some attempts require to screw this behavior.

Comment: no request is not from .aspx page its from other server

Comment: what is your Complete URl with query string

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code as per the values in your URL.

if your URl is  = `http://localhost:3039/test.aspx?valuestr=abc&randomnum=99389`

then you can use the below code

```
 string valuestr = Request.QueryString["valuestr"];
 string randomnum= Request.QueryString["valuestr"];
 Response.Write(valuestr );
 Response.Write(randomnum);
```

do let me know in case you require any help

Comment: Thanks, @Manoj Bhardwaj my Uri is http://localhost:50844/Success.aspx and I am getting Empty in Request.QueryString as well as Request.Form, However, the same request can be received in a java servlet using request.GetParameter("param name").

Comment: great can you please share the code from where you are attaching the values and redirecting.

Comment: I don't have the code from where they are attaching the values. I am posting my request on their page contains a parameter success URL after successful transaction they will send the request back to that URL.

Comment: In C# in page_load method, I am trying to get the data using request object but there is no value in `Request.Form` or in `Request.QueryString`.When I checked raw request in Fiddler I can see the values. is there any other way to get those values. FYI fiddler raw request data is attached to question.

Comment: then it will not work unless they have query string or session used from old page to new page.

Comment: Whenever there are payments info then query strings will not be preferable so some of the sites use sessions. So you need to get some documentation from the old page owner what actually they are using or how they are passing and how you can retrieve.

Comment: On changing target framework from dotNet framework 4.6.1 to 4.0, I am getting request data in `Request.Form` object